# How extract the int from a FsCheck.Gen.choose

Tags: f#, fscheck

I'm new on F#, and can't see how extract the int value from:

```
let autoInc = FsCheck.Gen.choose(1,999)
```

The compiler say the type is `Gen<int>`, but can't get the int from it!. I need to convert it to decimal, and both types are not compatible.

Comment: Have you looked through the functionality in the [`Gen` module](https://fsharp.github.io/FsCheck/reference/fscheck-gen.html)?

Comment: Yes. But I don't understand this code. The code say ` let choose (l, h) = rand |> map (range (l,h) >> fst) ` but can't dechiper what it mean

Comment: The result of that expression is not a number, but a _generator_ of numbers. It doesn't "contain" any particular number inside of it, so there is nothing to "extract". If you just want to generate a random number, use `System.Random`.

Comment: @mamcx : Well, that's the source code for `Gen.choose`, but I didn't link you to the source code for a reason -- I linked you to the _documentation_, which you should read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a consumer's point of view, you can use the `Gen.sample` combinator which, given a generator (e.g. `Gen.choose`), gives you back some example values.

The signature of `Gen.sample` is:

```
val sample : size:int -> n:int -> gn:Gen<'a> -> 'a list

(* `size` is the size of generated test data
   `n`    is the number of samples to be returned
   `gn`   is the generator (e.g. `Gen.choose` in this case) *)
```

You can ignore `size` because `Gen.choose` ignores it, as its distribution is uniform, and do something like:

```
let result = Gen.choose(1,999) |> Gen.sample 0 1 |> Seq.exactlyOne |> decimal

(* 0 is the `size` (gets ignored by Gen.choose)
   1 is the number of samples to be returned *)
```

The `result` should be a value in the closed interval *[1, 999]*, e.g. *897*.

Answer (score 2):

Hi to add to what Nikos already told you, this is how you can get an decimal between 1 and 999:

```
#r "FsCheck.dll"

open FsCheck

let decimalBetween1and999 : Gen<decimal> =
    Arb.generate |> Gen.suchThat (fun d -> d >= 1.0m && d <= 999.0m)

let sample () = 
    decimalBetween1and999
    |> Gen.sample 0 1 
    |> List.head
```

you can now just use `sample ()` to get a random decimal back.

In case you just want integers between 1 and 999 but have those converted to `decimal` you can just do:

```
let decimalIntBetween1and999 : Gen<decimal> =
    Gen.choose (1,999)
    |> Gen.map decimal

let sampleInt () = 
    decimalIntBetween1and999
    |> Gen.sample 0 1 
    |> List.head
```

### what you probably *really* want to do instead

Is use this to write you some nice types and check properties like this (here using Xunit as a test-framework and the FsCheck.Xunit package:

```
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit

type DecTo999 = DecTo999 of decimal

type Generators = 
    static member DecTo999 =
        { new Arbitrary<DecTo999>() with
            override __.Generator = 
                Arb.generate 
                |> Gen.suchThat (fun d -> d >= 1.0m && d <= 999.0m)
                |> Gen.map DecTo999
        }

[<Arbitrary(typeof<Generators>)>]
module Tests =

  type Marker = class end

  [<Property>]
  let ``example property`` (DecTo999 d) =
    d > 1.0m
```

Comment: Or pipe into `Operators.decimal<^T>`, e.g. `.. |> Gen.sample 0 1 |> Seq.exactlyOne |> decimal`

Comment: yes there are a couple of options - pick whatever you like

Answer (score 1):

`Gen<'a>` is a type that essentially abstracts a function `int -> 'a` (the actual type is a bit more complex, but let's ignore for now). This function is pure, i.e. when given the same int, you'll get the same instance of 'a back every time. The idea is that FsCheck generates a bunch of random ints, feeds them to the `Gen` function, out come random instances of the type `'a` you're interested in, and feeds those to a test.

So you can't really get out *the* int. You have in your hands a function that given an int, generates another int.

`Gen.sample` as described in another answer essentially just feeds a sequence of random ints to the function and applies it to each, returning the results.

The fact that this function is pure is important because it guarantees reproducibility: if FsCheck finds a value for which a test fails, you can record the original int that was fed into the `Gen` function - rerunning the test with that seed is guaranteed to generate the same values, i.e. reproduce the bug.